# regex to require a positive numeric value (5,2) forbidding leading zero

Tags: regex

Can a regex pattern enforce the following combination of constraints on a numeric value?

```
     the number must be >= 1 and <= 999 
     (decimal point cannot be the first character in the string?)

     the number can be an integer or a number with a fractional component

     when it has a fractional component, 
     no more than 2 digits to the right of the decimal point 
     EDIT: but at least one digit to the right

     must not have leading zero(s)
```

Comment: Which Programming language you are referring to?

Comment: what have you tried? ..which language?..don't try to do everything with regex..!

Comment: Why do you assume that I am trying to do this with regex? Maybe there's somebody in my organization who wants to do everything with regex and maybe I'm saying it would be better to write a function.

Comment: from your description - it's a normal `DECIMAL(3,2)` variable (in terms of SQL, for example). I think regex is a bad idea for that.

Comment: Maybe I am looking for answers that say, enforcing the >=1 and <= 999 is not really something you'd want to do with regex.  I didn't ask "How", I asked "Can".

Comment: @Tim if you're asking "Can?", here is an answer - **Yes, it can**

Comment: Any finite list of strings can be matched. Worse case scenario, list all the possible values, stick them together with | :-)

Comment: Frederic Cheung: yes, that is a worst-case scenario :-)

Comment: @FrederickCheung, no, this will work only if list is finite while regex can describe even infinite sets. (so not every set can be recounted through `|` - so not every regex could be recounted that way)

Comment: I did say finite, and the current case is a finite list of strings

Comment: @Anirudh, the things that give me trouble are how to require the number to be between 1 and 999 inclusive; how to make sure there are only two numbers to the right of the decimal point when it exists; and how to prevent the leading zero.  I would prefer to write this as a function because I have no idea how to handle the conditional aspects of the requirement (if the decimal point exists) or how to enforce the numeric range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl syntax:

```
^+?(?:(?:999(?:\.0{1,2})?)|(?:(?!999)[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

Comment: his doesn't forbid leading zeros, it explicitly ignores them. Also, it allows more than 2 decimal digits. Did you read the Ops requirements?

Comment: @SvenS, updated accordingly, thanks

Comment: @Perreal. I have to thank you for your answer. My colleague the regex-lover thanks you even more because he has won the argument :-)

Comment: @perreal Looks good now :)

Comment: @pguardiario That's desired, see the OPs list of requirements

Comment: @pguardiario Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. You're right of course, contrary to the requirements, it matches 999.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes..

```
^(?!999[.](0*[1-9]+$))(?!0|[.])\d{1,3}([.]\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: This looks like it wouldn't match 0.5 which I assume is legal - i think the stuff about leading zeroes is trying to exclude 020 for example

Comment: @FrederickCheung it's ok, since OP wants `1<=x<=999`

Comment: Oops, my bad. It does however match 999.5 which is out of bounds then

Comment: Yes, trying to prevent 020 or 002.  Also, when there's a decimal point, there should be at least one number to the right.  1.1 is valid but 1. is not.

Comment: @pguardiario nice observation..edited the ans

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with this one:

```
/^
(?:
  999.0*                      # 999.000
  |                           # or
  [1-9]\d{,2}((?<!999)\.\d+)? # 1-998 plus optional .\d*
)
$/x
```